# Can't see any image on this site

Tags: support, image

I can't see any image (profile picture, images in post, etc) on this site. I think it is due to AdBlock or Ghostery, but I am not sure and I would like to see images without disabling them.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for avatars (profile pictures), make sure to permit Gravatar in Ghostery (under "Widgets"). Images in posts are usually hosted on Imgur – no idea where that should be blocked.

I'm using both mentioned tools myself, that's how I know about Ghostery – but I never had an issue here concerning Adblock. Though that might rather be related to a subscribed filter list. Try disabling Adblock for a moment and reload the page; if that makes images showing up you know at least that. Then consider whitelisting all SE sites in Adblock – or checking the filters, if you prefer.

Comment: I've just re-enabled Gravatar and it works perfectly, Thanks !

Comment: Glad to read – and thanks for confirming! So the "other images" were fixed with the same thing? Or was that some Adblock subscribed list's entry?

Comment: Every images of the site are displayed when re-enabling Gravatar :)

Comment: Ugh! Didn't expect that – but all the better then :)